# Unbind or remove functions?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-events, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm having some difficulty with the accordion UI.

I want a set of divs to be an accordion when the window is a certain size (below 1024) and just divs (above 1024)

The code that I have works if the window is greater than 1024 and then I resize to a smaller window. But if I expand the window it won't turn off the accordion.

Here's the code, what am I not getting right?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var width = $(window).width();
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (width < 1024){
    $('#accordion').accordion();
    }

});
$(window).resize(function() {
var width = $(window).width();
if (width < 1024) {
    $('#accordion').accordion();
} if (width > 1024) {
    $('.accordion').remove();
}});    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things in the code you posted:

1. The method to get rid of an accordion is not .remove() but [.destroy()](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#method-destroy).
2. You changed from an id selector ("#accordion") to a class selector (".accordion"). It's possible for that to work--assuming the elements have both that id and that class--but not recommended; you should be consistent about the selectors within a given function/context.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But I corrected the ID selector so they are both the same and then changed .remove(); to .destroy(); but it still didn't work. it's just this one element that I want to turn the accordion on and off <ul id="accordion"> with the browser width. Do you have any other recommendations on hot achieve this? I'm pretty new to jquery so I'm hoping that it's not too complicated.

Comment: Sorry I'm stupid. I realized you were talking about .accordion('destroy'); not $('#accordion').destroy(); Thanks so much.